# undefined method `configuration_hash' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I tried to run rails g devise admin, this error occurred. I already did devise:install.

Does anyone have idea?

```
 invoke  active_record
/usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/generators/active_record/devise_generator.rb:100:in `ar_config': undefined method `configuration_hash' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.8.0/lib/generators/active_record/devise_generator.rb:94:in `postgresql?'
        .....

2021/12/25 02:35:59 Command exited with error: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a multi-database environment. If you have that too, I think you skipped the last line of this error message:

```
      invoke  active_record
/gems/ruby/3.2.0/gems/devise-4.9.2/lib/generators/active_record/devise_generator.rb:100:in `ar_config': undefined method `configuration_hash' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

ActiveRecord::Base.configurations.configs_for(env_name: Rails.env, name: "primary").configuration_hash
                                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

ActiveRecord seems to expect a "primary" database in the database.yml. See here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#setting-up-your-application

So what I did to fix this was replace all occurrences of `default` with `primary` in the database.yml and I was good.

This surely has side effects though ...